# Linker error after integrating firebase database

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

After integrate the firebase database, I'm getting linker error:

[image: Linker Error]

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
>         vtable for leveldb::Iterator in FirebaseDatabase(iterator.o)

Comment: anyone can u help me i am using xcode 8.2.1 objective-c

Comment: it will not helps u to resolve ur issue @shankar please give me what u done in code and when u getting these issues

Comment: thank you for your reply i correct it my self

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR linker error after installed pod files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After integrating firebase pods u have to open .workspace file instead of .xproject file and after opening the file goto **build setting** -> **framework search path** then add $inherited into it . Then clean your build and run , hope it works fine..

Comment: yes it works same thing i did long before...thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you should link you target against  libc++.dylib library (Your app target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries).

Also you should add -ObjC flag as stated here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Answer (score 0):

If possible try installing FirebaseDatabase via cocoapods.

Cocoapods are quick to integrate and highly recommendable while integrating  multiple different SDKs.

You can find steps on

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup.

Answer (score 0):

what you provide info its not sufficient to helps you.

if u r copy the firebase files manually just don't use that process , its not recommended.

use cocoapods for integrating the Firebase its easy:   `https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup.`

for how to install cocoa pods check these steps:

1.First open your terminal

2.Then update your gem file with command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

3.Then give your project path

```
cd /your project path
```

4.Touch the Podifle

```
touch podfile
```

5.Open your podfile

```
open -e podfile
```

6.It will open a podfile like a text edit.then set your target .For example if you want to set up Google maps then your podfile should be like

```
use_frameworks!
target 'yourProjectName' do
    pod 'Firebase'
end
```

7.Then install the pod

pod install

or simply follow the link

`https://cocoapods.org/?q=firebase`